# Move orbitcontrol camera on circular path around object

Tags: javascript, three.js

newbie in threejs here.

I have a cube with different color on each face. The cube can be rotate using OrbitControl and I have 6 buttons in Dat.GUI to control the camera position. Objective is when clicking on "Animate to red", the orbitcontrol camera will move to the red face from its current position on a circular path, "Animate to blue" camera will move to the blue face and so on...

I have the "Animate to red" button somewhat working right now but I don't think my solution is right. Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks

Here is my codesandbox link https://syckkt.csb.app/

Answer (score 0):

So I've implemented a fix to your code here: https://exciting-haslett-vfbojd.csb.app/

The idea is to have a list of unit vectors representing each side, then animating the camera to that position. If the side is on the opposite side of the shape we animate to a perpendicular side first and then towards our target side after. Just check the code it's all in there.

Comment: Thanks for helping me @Kitanga. Your solution works but it doesn't give me the desired effect that I'm looking for, the camera doesn't move to the next position on a circular path. I want it to move just like when using orbitcontrol to rotate the box so that the box size stay the same during camera motion. I think it will have something to do with the circle position formula using Math.sin and Math.cos

Comment: Hi @Kitanga, I have updated my codes based on your idea and somewhat got it working the way I want with the 4 sides (yellow,red,purple,white). If I manually rotate the cube up/down using orbit control then my position calculation is wrong. Can you take a look to see if you have any other suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: So what you want is that if you rotate the camera then the game object also rotates right?

Comment: @user16484677 also aren't the controls WASD+Cursor-keys, or do you expect users to also use the orbit controls?

Comment: I expect the user to use the orbit controls most of the time. Whenever they want to go back to a specific face, all they need to do is clicking the button for that face and the camera/orbit control will move to there from its current position just like they manual do it with orbit control. 

The cube object itself is not rotating.

Comment: If you click “animate to red”, you will see the different between yours and mine. Your tween animate from yellow to red face on a straight line x,y,z. Mine is changing x,z on a circle path.